# Why does the derivative of the magnitude of a vector yield a different result to the magnitude of the derivative of a vector?

Tags: derivatives, vectors

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLOxD.png)
The time derivative of the posistion vector is the velocity vector, then we can take the magnitude of the posistion. Thats what part a doesand the magnitude is given to be 1953.3

But when you first take the magnitude of the posistion vector then divide that by the time derivative of the expression it gives 1935.5

So knowing this the magnitude of the velocity vector is not the same as the magnitude of the first time derivative of the posistion vector. Can someone please explain why that is the case?

Comment: Because $(g\circ f')(x)=(g\circ f)'(x)$ is not a thing.

Comment: Honest question:  why *should* they be the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are measuring two different things. The first measures the rate of change of the *distance from the origin*, whereas the other measures the magnitude of the rate of change of *position*. Position and distance from the origin are not the same.

Comment: A simple example is a vector valued function that sweeps a circle.

Comment: One very simple way to see that the two must be different: If you sit on the edge of a merry go round, then your distance to the center never changes. Hence the rate of change of this distance is zero. But you are certainly not at rest!